# Basic Authentication in UIWebView cancelled before user can enter credentials

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, uiwebview

I've got a `UIWebView` which should work with basic authentication. It can see when a user is being challenged for authentication, however `didRecieveauthenticationChallenge` is called twice, the first time trying to authenticate the user, the second time cancelling the authentication challenge.

The problem is it's cancelled before the user has the chance to enter their credentials. The `UIAlertView` shows and requests credentials, however the method is called again while the alert view is being filled in and runs `[[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];`

Any ideas why it could be getting called twice? Am I asking for credentials at the wrong point?

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
{
    NSLog(@"got auth challange");
    _didChallenge = YES;

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        _authed = YES;

        // Ask user for their credentials
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" message:@"Please enter username and password:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alertView setTag:1];
        alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
        [alertView show];

        // Use credentials for authentication
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] password:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:1] text] persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
{
    NSLog(@"received response via nsurlconnection");
    if (_didChallenge) {
        _authed = YES;

        // Make new request to UIWebView, which will use the new saved auth info
        [serverWebView loadRequest:[connection currentRequest]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//In This Mehtod  run a while loop until you present Alert view and and enter credentials 

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{

///Show Alert View

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(WaitForCredentialDialog) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];  //To stop execution to move further until user enter credentials or cancel Authentication.

//Then do code of canceling or authenticating .

}

//Here  DialogResult is a variable which will make while loop run until its value is -1 and reset its value to 1 or 0 when AlertView's Button is clicked 
- (void) WaitForCredentialDialog{
    NSDate*               LoopUntil;
    //****************************************************************************
    LoopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
    while ((DialogResult==-1) && ([[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:LoopUntil]))
    {
        LoopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
    }
    //****************************************************************************
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

   DialogResult =1 ;

}
```

//For more details see this link https://code.google.com/p/tkawebview/downloads/detail?name=tkaurlprotocol.zip&can=2&q=